# Changing the default fonts, colours and padding of plots in Mathematica 13

Tags: plotting, graphics, options, default

### Default legend font

After a while of playing around with the option inspector, I've managed to change the default font and colour of the axis labels and tick labels of a 2D plot, as well as the default colour of the axes:

[image]

However, the font of the legend has eluded me. Is there a way to change the default (so that I don't have to manually specify the font every time)?

### Default plot colours

In a similar vein, is it possible to change the default function-plot colours? The default blue-orange-green-scheme is not to my liking.

[image]

### Default plot range padding

Finally, why does the `PlotRangePadding` option in the option inspector not work? I've set it to `None` (also tried `0` earlier), and it doesn't seem to do anything (I've made sure I'm changing the global preferences):

[image]

### Explanatory note

What I'd like to do is change the default options so that plots look the way I want them to in all future documents, forever, without me having to specify options unless I want a specific plot to look a specific way. I don't want to create a custom theme which I can then call into the options for `Plot` or `Plot3D` or `ListPlot` or whatever, because that means I have to type the theme-related stuff (i.e. more than zero characters) into the graphics options every time.

As stated by ArgentoSapiens in a comment on another question, "I [...] mean that there should be zero clicks or keystrokes between creating a new document and making a plot with the desired default [appearance]." Additionally, "behavio[u]r on other people's computers doesn't matter"; I only wish to change how things are displayed on my computer.

Comment: I'd suggest you create a custom theme, and them set it a default using `$PlotTheme` in your init file. This gives you the desired default appearance together with the nice properties of a theme (merging of settings etc)

Comment: Again, though, that doesn't work for me because it means I have to manually set the theme of every plot. I'd like to change the appearance with zero keystrokes necessary.

Comment: That's why I suggested to set [`$PlotTheme`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PlotTheme.html) in your [`init.m`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html) file to the desired value. That way, the default plot theme will be whatever you choose. And if you define your custom theme in the `init.m` file as well, you'll have to do no extra typing at all